# sum two selected box onchange in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have 4 tables

1. customers

   - id, nama, alamat
2. helmets

   - id, customer_id, treatment_id, parfume_id, delivery_id, jenis, total
3. treatments

   - id, nama, harga
4. parfumes

   - id, nama, harga
5. deliveries

   - id, nama, harga

so I want to sum harga from treatments, parfumes, and deliveries into total in helmet, also I want to show it on page with onchange. how do I save the total from javascript to the table and fill the value with id not with harga on the helmet

this is my blade

```
<HTML>
<form class="form-contact contact_form" action="/addorder" onchange="return calcTotal(this)"  method="post" id="orderForm">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <p>Nama : </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="nama" id="nama" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Nama Anda">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <h4>Nomor Whatsapp : </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="no_wa" id="no_wa" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Nomor Whatsapp">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <p>Nomor telepon : </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="no_tlp" id="no_tlp" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Nomor yang dapat dihubungi">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <p>Jenis Helm : </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="jenis" id="jenis" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Jenis/series helm anda">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <p>Alamat : </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="alamat" id="alamat" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Alamat anda">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <center><h2><br>Pilih</h2></center>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <p>Treatment : </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10 yuk">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select name="harga_t" class="form-control" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                                        <option value="2"></option>
                                        @foreach($treatment as $t)
                                            <option value="{{$t->biaya}}">{{$t->nama}} - Rp. {{$t->biaya}},00<div name="harga_t" id="harga_t" value="{{$t->id}}"> </div></option>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                        <!-- <div type="hidden" class="divprice" ></div> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <p>Parfum : </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select name="harga_p" class="form-control" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                                        @foreach($parfum as $p)
                                            <option value="{{$p->biaya}}" >{{$p->nama}} - Rp. {{$p->biaya}},00<div name="harga_p" id="harga_p" value="{{$p->id}}">  </div></option>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <h5>Metode Ambil : </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select name="harga_d" class="form-control" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                                        @foreach($deliver as $d)
                                            <option value="{{$d->biaya}}" >{{$d->nama}} - <div name="harga_d" id="harga_d" value="{{$d->id}}"> Rp. {{$d->biaya}},00  </div></option>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                        <!-- <div type="hidden" class="divprice"></div> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10" name="total" id="total" value=""></div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="status" id="status" type="hidden" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Enter Subject" value="Menunggu konfirmasi">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm boxed-btn">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
</html>
```

and this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcTotal(Form){
        var sum = 0;
        for(i=0; i < oSels.length; i++){
            sum += new Number(oSels[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
        $('#total').val(sum)
        return false;
    }
    window.onload=function(){
        oSels = document.getElementById('orderForm').getElementsByTagName('select');
        for(i=0; i < oSels.length; i++){
            oSels[i].onchange=function(){
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '';
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

this is my controller

```
public function addOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->nama = $request->nama;
        $customer->no_wa = $request->no_wa;
        $customer->no_tlp = $request->no_tlp;
        $customer->alamat = $request->alamat;
        $customer->save();

      
        $helmet = new Helmet();
        $helmet->customer_id = $customer->id;
        $helmet->treatment_id = $request->harga_t;
        $helmet->parfum_id = $request->harga_p;
        $helmet->delivery_id = $request->harga_d;
        $helmet->jenis = $request->jenis;
        $helmet->total = $request->total;
        $helmet->status = $request->status;
        $helmet->save();

        return redirect('/order');
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, what problems have you faced? and what you have tried so far? another suggestion is to use `English` inside code for making it more readable for the coders/developers